# Modbus sniffer tool required

Tags: modbus

I am looking for a good professional modbus sniffer tool to scan the master slave communication. Please any one have idea ?

Regards
Dani

Answer (score 7):

You could use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Excellent tool. Modbus TCP supported.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a RS232 or RS485 communication line, I suggest you RSMonitor

[RSMonitor](http://www.sirius.to.it/it/RS%20Monitor.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you get the right connections setup to monitor a serial stream. [Realterm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/) works well.